# Problems connecting Blueprism to database

Tags: sql, sql-server, blueprism

Good morning

I'm starting my training in BluePrism and I'm having some problems. I installed everything following the manual and I try to generate some processes but when I try to run them I found this:

Not connected to CPX-2UKBS0TPW5O - can't start process

In the control room the resource CPX-.... appears as offline. I used SQL Server Management Studio to connect the database and it works. But when I try to run the Blue Prism Server from Services it doesn't work. I use a local database if it helps you to solve my problem.

Finally if I try to run from BPServer.exe it works but it appears as no running in Services.

```
    [2018-09-25 10:56:51] : Loading configuration...
[2018-09-25 10:56:51] : Select configuration and click Start to continue
[2018-09-25 10:57:28] : Connecting to database using connection 'BPAccess_Test'...
[2018-09-25 10:57:28] : Starting listener...
[2018-09-25 10:57:28] : Using Transport mechanism - WCFSOAPMessageWindows
[2018-09-25 10:57:30] : ...listening on http://0:1433/bpserver
[2018-09-25 10:57:30] : Starting Scheduler...
[2018-09-25 10:57:30] : Scheduler: Starting background thread scheduler : checking 900000ms back for missed schedules
[2018-09-25 10:57:30] : Scheduler: [BT]  Creating system thread : SchedulerThread_1
[2018-09-25 10:57:31] : Server startup sequence complete.
[2018-09-25 10:57:31] : Scheduler: Starting
[2018-09-25 10:57:31] : Scheduler: Last activation time: 25-Sep-18 10:42:30 AM; Next activation time 31-Dec-99 11:59:59 PM
[2018-09-25 10:57:31] : Scheduler: Waiting forever
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Blue Prism recommends using all locally-hosted components for training. Any particular reason why you have the components remotely hosted? Additionally, could you provide a high-level network diagram showing what network components are between you and the remote resources you're attempting to connect to?

Comment: I have no idea because I'm really new to this world. I just wanted to install it locally but looks like i did it wrong...

Comment: You can create a local database using localhost\SQLExpress if you do that then you can run your proces using your own locla machine as a resource. Scheduler won't work because it is mange by app server but for start RPA I think it should work.